# Combining multiple blocks: check alphabet, check string length, check if palindrome

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

if (strcmp(strrev(inputarray),temp) == 0) {
        printf("Palindrome\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not palindrome\n");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a program to prompt user to enter a string:
...............
iii) check if string is a palindrome, if yes, output palindrome, if not, not a palindrome

When I test the parts, works well.

When combining them all, I get output 'not palindrome' even when it is. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are never initializing `temp`.
before doing `strcmp` do `strcpy(temp, inputarray)`

Comment: Thanks. Tried this, now getting stack around inputarray corrupted. Still output: not palindrome (when it is).

Comment: But `printf("%s\n", inputaray))` is printing your char[] correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have printf("%s Please enter string>"); 
This could lead to corruption, please try after removing %s from this printf statement

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your palindrome function instead of `strrev` (which is not standard C).  I noticed that when I tried using `strcmp(strrev(str), str)==0)` to test for a palindrome I always got "is palindrome" too.

```
int ispalindrome(char *str, int len)
{   
    char *p = &str[0];
    char *q = &str[len - 1];
    do
    {
        if(p >= q)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    } while (*p++ == *q--);
    return 0;
}
```